# How to make a webpage with an icon on the iOS home screen open Safari with full functioning?

Tags: ios, safari

In iOS 17.3.1, is there a way to put an icon for a webpage onto the home screen so that when clicked it opens Safari in fully-functioning mode, complete with address bar and so on, rather than in a restricted mode that only shows the given webpage?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  You should be able to save a bookmark directly to the Home Screen. I tried it with several different webpages and it opened the bookmark in Safari.

Comment: I think that a PWA (Progressive Web App) may cause this issue. Some sites are written as a web app, where the whole site is a javascript app.  They can then actually be run offline by the browser.  Clicking on such a "save" would probably restrict the browser.

Comment: @fsb - I assume it's opening in Safari because after clicking on the icon on the home screen I can click on links and navigate, and I haven't got any other browsers installed. But there's no address bar at the top or bar with buttons at the bottom for bookmarks, tabs, going back, etc. - there are none of the usual functions that are available when I browse to a webpage. (Everything's fine when I open Safari and type in the URL, or when I click on the icon on the favourites screen.)

Comment: @RohitGupta - I'm not sure I wholly understand, but the page I'm having this problem with is my own webpage and it doesn't contain or call any Javascript.

Comment: Is this an attempt to rephrase the same problem as [your question with a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/469087/5472)? We might need to know what web server you have chosen to test this out and design / share your app.

Comment: @bmike - No, they are 2 different questions. The other question is about what icon shows up. This question is about what happens when an icon (whatever it may be) is clicked on. I haven't written an app. This is a simple webpage containing text, and a few images, some linkified. The HTML and CSS are not much more advanced than entry level. I have tried to phrase the question as generally as possible so that the solution if someone posts one will benefit many users. If someone could explain the conditions for Safari displaying the mentioned behaviour on iOS, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Great, I wanted to be sure I understood both before answering.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use shortcuts to do this. Apple intends for the chrome to fade away on Safari 15, so to escape that default behavior, I believe your best bet is to save a workflow to the Home Screen and assign an icon using that mechanism as needed.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/open-create-and-run-a-shortcut-apda283236d7/ios